# How to generate dependent Graphs

Tags: angular, graph

I would like to generate two graphs say graph-1 and graph-2 where graph-2 depends on graph-1.

For example,
Graph-1 is Population Vs Year & Graph-2 is Male-Female Population

Graph-1

[image]

Graph-2

[image]

So, here Graph-2 depends on Graph-1.

What i want is, when i click on a year, the values from that year should be hidden in Graph-1 and simultaneously reflect the total number of Male-Female number in Graph-2.

I want the dependable graph for an Angular Project.I am able to individually generate the graphs using amCharts in my Angular Application. But no solution for dependable graphs.

Comment: You need to have both graphs depend on the same data, not have one graph depend on the other. Apart from that, I'm afraid this question is way too vast for SO. You're basically asking us for free consulting work with something this broad. I'm sure it wasn't your intention; I suggest you show the research you have done and some things you have tried. You'll get far more positive replies.

Comment: @WillAlexander Its not some research or something. The graphs attached were just for example. And yes my both data depend on same data. If u see amcharts, if u click on a variable in legend then the values related to it will be hidden, so here in graph two if i click on Female option in legend, then the bargraph for female will be hidden. so, when that happens i want the same to reflect in the other graph. like in each year only male count should be shown as female is hidden.

Comment: When I say that the graphs need to depend on the same data, I mean that selecting a subgroup should filter the entire dataset as opposed to depending on the UI component. And when I say you should show your research, I mean that it's generally considered polite on SO to show what you've tried and what you've found when researching your problem. Research is a large part of our jobs as developers.